# two static libraries that use different libstdc++ versions

Tags: c++, gcc, static-libraries

I am working on a project where we use an old version of libstdc++. I have just introduced a new library statically linked, that requires a newer version of the libstdc++. I have installed both versions of libstdc++ installed. Is there a way to compile my program with gcc and the new library?

Comment: Please clearify a bit; do you want to use the new library only or both ?

Answer (score 4):

Compile with the newer version of libstdc++ as [this library is forward compatible](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html).